# Prove that if $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges, then $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} A_{k}$ converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Suppose that  $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers.let $\{n_{k}\}$ be an increasing sequence of positive integers, and let $A_{k} = a_{n_{k}} + a_{n_{k}+1}+ ... +a_{n_{k +1}-1}$, for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that if $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges, then  $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} A_{k}$ converges. Give an example to show that the converse is not true.

Could anyone give me a hint please?especially I do not understand why $A_{k}$ looks like this and what does the author trying to teach me by this question? and why we are starting from $k = 1$  not $k =0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that for $K\geq1$, we have 
$$\sum_{k=1}^KA_k=\sum_{n=n_1}^{n_{K+1}-1}a_n,$$
and use the Cauchy criterion for convergence.  The exercise is trying to tell you that if the sum converges, then we can group consecutive terms together without affecting convergence.

As for the issue of $k=0$ vs. $k=1$,  this is just a choice of style, depending on whether you say $0\in\mathbb N$ or $0\notin\mathbb N$.

Comment: Could  you please give a numeric example for me for the two serieses please?

Comment: Could you provide more details about using the Cauchy criterion please?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: The sequence of partial sums of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k$ is a subsequence of the sequence of partial sums of $\sum_{n=n_1}^{\infty}a_n.$

Comment: Could  you please give a numeric example for me for the two serieses please?

Comment: I think the second series starts from $n = 1$ not $n = n_{1}$ ? or this is not correct?